# React 18 - How to detect if concurrent mode is active?

Tags: reactjs, shared-libraries, react-18

My component library should run in both React 18 (createRoot/ ReactDom.render) and in older React versions.

There's logic that fixes an issue caused by concurrent rendering, and I need to apply it only in case it's active (within createRoot).

Detecting react version alone is not sufficient since application can be rendered in "legacy" mode with ReactDom.render.

How can I detect if concurrent rendering is enabled ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a standard way to check this, but here a few things that come to mind.

Firstly, notice that React's `createRoot()` returns a `ReactDOMRoot` instance:

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

// `ReactDOMRoot` instance
console.log(root);
```

However, `ReactDOM.render()` returns `null` regardless of the version:

```js
const res = ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);

// `null`
console.log(res);
```

[*Link to a React 18 StackBlitz app where both snippets are sampled.*](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-25dfcj?file=index.tsx)

So, the first approach would be to check whether the result is `null` or not. If it's `null`, you can be sure that there is no way Concurrent Mode is enabled.

---

If the above approach is not sufficient, the `ReactDOMRoot` instance returned by `createRoot()` has some meaningful information. If you inspect the console, you should see something like this:

```js
ReactDOMRoot {_internalRoot: FiberRootNode }
```

The `_internalRoot` property of that object has a `tag` property which basically indicates whether a Concurrent Root or a Legacy Root is used:

```js
{
  /* ... */
  tag: 1,
  /* ... */
}
```

The value of `1` corresponds to the [ConcurrentRoot value](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactRootTags.js#L13).

However, if the result would be `null`, then it means `ReactDOM.render()`(i.e. legacy version) has been used, so I don't see why you'd bother checking that `tag` property(not to mention it is behind a property prefixed with `_`), but I thought it would be interesting to share this information :).

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve this instance from within a component ?
As stated, it's a components library, not an application (otherwise I'd simply use some shared configuration)

Comment: @TheZver I'm not aware of any way of doing so from a function component. There might be one from a class component, although not entirely sure.

Comment: Too bad. 
I'll try to come up with a hook that detects state batching in async logic, which is also enabled along with concurrent rendering..